# Rejection method on a landau pdf

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have been trying to create a random number generator for a landau PDF using the rejection acceptance algorithm. The problem is it seems to take a very long time to compile and the generated values don't seem to follow the PDF.
This is  the code I tried to use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy  as np
import time
from sympy import sqrt,exp,pi

a=0   # xmin
b=150 # xmax

h=0.25 # ymax
variables = [] #list for variables
def f(x):
    return 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-1/2*((x-25)+exp(-(x-25))))  #probability density function


reject = 0   # number of rejections
start = time.time()
while len(variables) < 100000:  #I want to generate 100 000 variables
    u1 = random.uniform(a,b)
    u2 = random.uniform(0,h)

    if u2 <= f(u1):
        variables.append(u1)
    else:
        reject +=1
end = time.time()

print("Time: ", end-start)
print("Rejection: ", reject)
xx = np.linspace(a,b,150)

plt.hist(variables,50, density=1)
plt.show()
```

Any thoughts would be welcome

Comment: Edited, please check again.

Comment: Now reedited, please check!

Comment: note that `scipy.stats.moyal(25).rvs(100_000)` is [supposed to be](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moyal.html) a good approximation of this, and only takes 10milliseconds to generate 100k samples on my laptop

Answer (score 2):

Why sympy ??? A rejection method has always performance issues, if you combine this with sympy.... that's just not a good idea. I suggest you replace the first block of you script above with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy  as np
import time
import random
from scipy import sqrt,exp,pi
```

then at least it runs (some warnings that you could easily fix yourself) and produces the correct output:

```
Time:  61.50497007369995
Rejection:  3671570
```

[image]

***Why is it slow?***

Because you discard random values with probability `1-f(u1)/0.25` which is small only around the peak of your distribution at `u1 ~ 25`. It actually becomes numerically `1.0` far before your reach `u1=150` since `f2(150)=12.8675100380087668e-28`! This means you discard 100% of random number tries for larger values of `u1` which is very inefficient.

A great way to speed up your code is to reduce the range of `u1`. Just change `b=50` and you get:

```
Time:  20.477684020996094
Rejection:  1145527
```

--> three times faster and same result.

***Is this all?***

No, if you really care for speed, you should not produce `u2` always on the 0 to 0.25 interval. You can use any upper bound as long as it stays smaller than the actual Landau distribution. It has to be an "envelope".   This could dramatically increase computing time since you lower your rejection probability. For a Landau this is, however not simple due to its very long tails. But you may for sure find something at least in a specific range of `u1`.

A rather stupid approach I just tested is to split your problem into four intervals [a,b) = [0,27), [27,30), [30,35), [35,50) with upper bounds on u2 of 0.25, 0.11, 0.05, 0.01 and obtain another factor of almost 2 speedup:

```
Time:  12.69986867904663
Rejection:  661561
```

of course, again, with statistically identical result:

[image]

with some work you can get much better than that. The edited example proof-of-principle code is (this can be done better/nicer):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy  as np
import time
import random
from scipy import sqrt,exp,pi

a=0   # xmin
b=50 # xmax

#h=0.25 # ymax
variables = [] #list for variables
envelope = []
def f(x):
    return 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-1/2*((x-25)+exp(-(x-25))))  #probability density function


reject = 0   # number of rejections
start = time.time()
while len(variables) < 100000:  #I want to generate 100 000 variables
    u1 = random.uniform(a,b)
    h = 0.01
    if (u1<35): h=0.05
    if (u1<30): h=0.11
    if (u1<27): h=0.25
    
    u2 = random.uniform(0,h)

    if u2 <= f(u1):
        variables.append(u1)
        envelope.append(h/0.25)
    else:
        reject +=1
end = time.time()

print("Time: ", end-start)
print("Rejection: ", reject)
xx = np.linspace(a,b,150)

plt.hist(variables, 50, weights=envelope,  density=1)
plt.show()
```

***Beat that***

After reading the comments below I want to share my ultimate performance making full use of numpy vectorization:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy  as np
import time

a=0   # xmin
b=50 # xmax

def f(x):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-1/2*((x-25)+np.exp(-(x-25))))

start = time.time()

n = 100000
u1 = np.random.rand(n)*(b-a)+a
h = np.full(n, 0.01)
h[u1<35] = 0.05
h[u1<30] = 0.11
h[u1<27] = 0.25
u2 = np.random.rand(n) * h

accept = u2 <= f(u1)
reject = n - np.count_nonzero(accept)

end = time.time()

print("Time: ", end-start)
print("Rejection: ", reject)

plt.hist(u1[accept], 50, weights=h[accept],  density=1)
plt.show()
```

with this output:

```
Time:  0.015883445739746094
Rejection:  86907
```

This is a 3892-times performance improvement compared to my initial version and I am sure compared to sympy it is even much more than that. It really matters to understand what, why and how we are coding.

In fact, I would be interested: Is there someone who can further improve on this latest version of the code?

Comment: Thank you very much! It does help, but not sure how to split the intervals into segments_may show that strip of code please)

Comment: Its also sped up after using ```from numpy import sqrt,exp,pi``` instead of scipy )

Comment: I added a version of the code in my answer that actually makes use of vectorized numpy math. Check it out...